# Eclipse: Installation of a set of Plugins from the command line -> DefaultProfile is not current. Expected timestamp

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line, eclipse-plugin

We are trying to install a set of eclipse plugins from the commandline.

For this we are using the General command: [1]

The command works most of the times perfect.

But for some plugins we get a similar error: [2]

The only difference is the timestamp.

As a result the plugins could not be installed from the command line. When installing the plugin in the UI everything is working.

Any idea what is causing the error [2]. Might this be an issue with the Installation sequence? How can we set the Defaultprofile

Thanks for a hint.

Best Regards

Frank

[1] 
eclipsec.exe
-application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository  -installIU  -destination C:/developmenttools/JDT/4.3/eclipse -profile DefaultProfile -followReferences

[2]

!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Profile DefaultProfile is not current. Expected timestamp 1392631752387 but was 1392631752387.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.SimpleProfileRegistry.lockProfile(SimpleProfileRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.director.PlanExecutionHelper.executePlan(PlanExecutionHelper.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.director.PlanExecutionHelper.executePlan(PlanExecutionHelper.java:23)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.director.app.DirectorApplication.executePlan(DirectorApplication.java:783)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.director.app.DirectorApplication.planAndExecute(DirectorApplication.java:776)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.director.app.DirectorApplication.performProvisioningActions(DirectorApplication.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.director.app.DirectorApplication.run(DirectorApplication.java:1063)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.director.app.DirectorApplication.start(DirectorApplication.java:1245)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like Eclipse bug [392818](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=392818). Comments in the bug report say:

> Not sure if this can be considered a bug; the guide for installing
>   software using the p2 director application (1) states that if you want
>   to run the provisioning operation from within the target you're
>   provisioning into you're not supposed to use the -destination
>   argument.
>
> The problem you're facing most likely stems from the fact that you're
>   trying to modify the platform while it is running. The -destination
>   flag assumes that the target you're provisioning into is not started.
>
> (1)
>   http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html
>   - "Running inside the target application" section.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your hint is saving our day :-).